# Why does the WordPress Backend doesn't show Navigations anymore?

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress Backend doesn't show Navigations

Since I've updated to WordPress Version 5.4.1, I can't access to the menus into the dashboard. (They're still visible on the frontend page). The debug info shows me

```
Trying to get property of non-object in /public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php on line 990
```

I think the specific line in nav-menus.php is this:

```
wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_locations[ $location ] )->name
```

Has anybody an idea whats the problem is or what I could do to bring them back to the backend?

Kind Regards,

Abhiijit

Comment: Have you tried to narrow down the problem by deactivating/activating plugins and the theme in use? Once you have access to the menu, make sure it is populated correctly.

Comment: @AlbertoMarin Thank you for your answer. I just tried out what happens if I deactivate all plugins. It doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: No problem, and have you tried to roll back to the previous working version of WordPress? It looks to me like your theme, or any plugin, is not compatible for some reason. Also, if you can check the PHP logs, and the console of your browser it might point you to the right direction.